# Use of async/await in console or web apps

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

As I understand it, the `async`/`await` feature in C# splits up the segments between `await` calls into callback methods that run on the calling thread after each awaited method has returned on a separate worker thread. The calling thread is "free" during the waiting time. The callback must be scheduled on the calling thread through some sort of event loop.

This event loop only exists in GUI applications like Windows Forms or WPF. Freeing this loop makes sure the UI remains responsive for other user interaction during long operations.

Console apps and web apps (ASP.NET) do not have such event loops, so this callback mechanism doesn't work. But then again, they do not have an event loop because they don't need one. There is no user trying to interact with the running program at any time, expecting immediate feedback. So there's no need to free the calling thread for that. It doesn't matter how many threads the operation uses, it only returns after the last bit is done.

So what's the use of `async` and `await` in console and web apps, or any kind of non-interactive code in general, like for example Windows services? How is that different or more efficient compared to simple synchronous calls?

I'm designing an API that is used by GUI and non-interactive (service and web) programs and have a hard time understanding how it behaves in non-GUI environments.

Comment: Still very useful if you don't want to use a thread per IO operation. Done properly, you can service hundreds of concurrent IO operations with only a handful of threads by going async.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point with async-await is that the calling thread is **always** freed up when you reach the first asynchronous point (i.e. the first `await` of an uncompleted task).

In UI apps you have a `SynchronizationContext` that posts the code after the awaits to the UI thread because code that interacts with the UI must be executed by the UI thread otherwise you'll get an exception. You can control that by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

In console apps (and services, etc.) there's no such need, so that code runs on some `ThreadPool` thread. The calling thread (which is likely to be also a `ThreadPool` thread) was freed up and was able to do other kinds of work in the meantime instead of blocking synchronously. So async-await improves scalability as it enables doing more work with the same amount of threads.

Comment: To increase scalability, async is only useful for I/O-bound work, not for CPU-bound work, right? Because it doesn't matter whether one or the other thread does the work. It only matters whether a thread is blocked or free and reactivated when an I/O operation completes. So this means, I only need async in my API for I/O work, not necessarily for long computations.

Answer (score 4):

[i3arnon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37878000/263693) is (as usual) excellent.

> So what's the use of async and await in console and web apps, or any kind of non-interactive code in general, like for example Windows services?

The primary benefit of async on the client side is responsiveness; the primary benefit of async on the server side is scalability.

> How is that different or more efficient compared to simple synchronous calls?

Client-side responsiveness and server-side scalability are achieved by the same mechanism: freeing up the calling thread. Thus, async is all about using fewer threads. On the server side, using fewer threads allows your app to make maximum use of the existing threadpool.

> As I understand it, the async/await feature in C# splits up the segments between await calls into callback methods that run on the calling thread after each awaited method has returned on a separate worker thread.

This is why I'm answering. I just can't let this one go. Every time "thread" is mentioned in this understanding, it's wrong. This part is correct: `await` does "split up" an `async` method into segments.

1) The callback methods are not run on the calling thread. Rather, `await` will capture a "context" and resume the method on that context. On ASP.NET apps and Console apps in particular, the context does not imply a particular thread. I explain how `await` captures context in detail on my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

2) Async APIs are not normally executed on worker threads. The entire point of async is to free up threads, so blocking thread pool threads wouldn't make sense. I explain how asynchronous I/O is almost threadless in my blog post on [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 0):

Async / await has nothing to do with multi threading, to quote [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx):

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be
>   created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async
>   method doesn't run on its own thread.

Async / await allows you to structure your code with regards to long running operations (could be CPU work or I/O work). So this is applicable to any type of program (GUI, Web Service, console etc)